# Adding a value to a 'datetime'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm getting an error

> Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow

when I use `case` function with date function anyone - please help me with this.

`ContractEndDate` column is of `datetime` datatype and accepts null values.

Thanks

```
case 
   when datepart(day, Contractenddate) > 21 
      then datename(month, dateadd(month, 1, Contractenddate)) + ' ' + datename(year, dateadd(month, 1, Contractenddate))
      else datename(month, Contractenddate) + ' ' + datename(year, Contractenddate)
end
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be most helpful

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  You code is doing string concatenation, not addition.

Comment: What's the value of `max(Contractenddate)`?

Comment: 9999-12-31 00:00:00.000

Comment: You'll have to figure out what you want with that date, you can't add a month to it.

Comment: i want month and year from my dates in this format case 
   when datepart(day, Contractenddate) > 21 
      then datename(month, dateadd(month, 1, Contractenddate)) + ' ' + datename(year, dateadd(month, 1, Contractenddate))
      else datename(month, Contractenddate) + ' ' + datename(year, Contractenddate)
end

Comment: I see that's what you want, but as said you can't add a month. So what you want is not possible, you have to decide what you want to do with that particular date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine, although I would write it as:

```
(case when datepart(day, Contractenddate) > 21
      then datename(month, dateadd(month, 1, Contractenddate)) + ' ' + datename(year, dateadd(month, 1, Contractenddate))
      else datename(month, Contractenddate) + ' ' + datename(year, Contractenddate)
 end)
```

(Note the use of `datepart()` for the numeric comparison.)

I suspect that you have unusual values for `Contractenddate`.  So, find the maximum value:

```
select max(Contractenddate)
from t;
```

I suspect it will be something like `9999-12-31`.  This is the maximum possible value and you cannot add a month to it (without getting an error).

EDIT:

To avoid the error, avoid the maximum date!

```
(case when datepart(day, Contractenddate) > 21 AND
           Contractenddate < '9999-12-01'
      then datename(month, dateadd(month, 1, Contractenddate)) + ' ' + datename(year, dateadd(month, 1, Contractenddate))
      else datename(month, Contractenddate) + ' ' + datename(year, Contractenddate)
 end)
```

Comment: this is the max value in my Table   (9999-12-31 00:00:00.000)